# Limiting API calls when using Unity and Vimeo SDK?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vimeo

I'm building a mobile app in Unity that streams video using the Vimeo SDK (and the AVPro video plugin.) I'm looking for some advice on optimizing API calls to avoid rate limiting issues, but I can't find much Unity-specific documentation on it. Specifically I want to know:

- How to access the number of remaining requests I can make/ log when API calls are made, through a script.
- If there's any good documentation or examples of caching video data efficiently in Unity. I'd like to be able to read from cached data as often as possible when loading videos or video info.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With regards to the rate limiting question, take a look at Vimeo's rate limiting guidelines here: https://developer.vimeo.com/guidelines/rate-limiting

In short, there are three headers returned in every response from api.vimeo.com:

- X-RateLimit-Limit: The total number of requests you are currently
  allowed to make before your rate limit resets.
- X-RateLimit-Remaining:
  The number of remaining requests you can make before you are rate
  limited.
- X-RateLimit-Reset: A UNIX timestamp detailing when the rate
  limit will reset.

Answer (score 0):

In order to optimize your API requests, you should group your videos together in some sort of collection on Vimeo. Then make a single API request to get all the video files.

For example, if you put your videos into a project, use this Get Project Videos endpoint: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/projects#get_project_videos

Like the [single video file request](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-unity-sdk/blob/master/Assets/Vimeo/Scripts/Services/VimeoApi.cs#L58) that is built into the Vimeo Unity plugin, you can also specify the fields of a collection request which will return an array of all the video files and drastically reduce your number of API calls.